# How would you test a module in expressionengine for errors?

Tags: php, testing, module, expressionengine

I've made a module for expressionengine, yet I have no idea how I'm supposed to test it for errors, so I tried installing it. But it didn't install and didn't return any errors, just refreshed the page. Anybody know how?

The files I have are like so :

third_party > upload_pictures :

- language > english > upload_pictures_lang.php
- views > index.php
- mcp.upload_pictures.php
- mod.upload_pictures.php
- tab.upload_pictures.php
- upd.upload_pictures.php

and the installer code

```
class Upload_pictures_upd
{
var $version='1.0';

function Upload_pictures_upd()
{
    $this->EE=& get_instance();
}

function install()
{
    $this->EE->load->dbforge();

    $data=array(
        'module_name'       =>'Picture uploader',
        'module_version'    =>$this->version,
        'has_cp_backend'    =>'y',
        'has_publish_fields'=>'y'
    );

    $this->EE->db->insert('modules',$data);

    $data=array(
        'class' =>'upload_pictures',
        'method'=>'run'
    );

    $this->EE->db->insert('actions',$data);

    $this->EE->load->library('layout');
    $this->EE->layout->add_layout_tabs($this->tabs(),'module_name');
    return true;
}

function update($current='')
{
    if ($current==$this->version)
    {
        return false;
    }
    elseif ($current<2.0)
    {
        //nothin
    }
    return true;
}

function uninstall()
{
    $this->EE->load->library("layout");
    $this->EE->layout->delete_layout_tabs($this->tabs(),'upload_pictures');
    return true;
}

function tabs()
{
    $tabs['upload pictures']=array(
        'upload_pictures_ids'=>array(
            'visible'       =>'true',
            'collapse'      =>'false',
            'htmlbuttons'   =>'false',
            'width'         =>'100%'
        )
    );
    return $tabs;
}
}
```

Comment: If you're unable to install your Module, you may be missing one or more of the required functions or files. The naming of your files are extremely important, too. If you suspect errors, enable the Output Profiler or Template Debugger and check Apache's or PHP's `error_logs`. Have you followed the [ExpressionEngine Module Development Tutorial](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/modules.html) in the Developer Documentation?

Comment: @rjb I did, I also updated the questions to show how I have the files set up.

Comment: It looks like all of your files are named correctly and in the proper places. When creating your Update File `upd.file.php`, make sure you capitalize the `Module_name`. If you do not, your module will not work and can be difficult to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Have you followed the [ExpressionEngine Module Development Tutorial](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/modules.html) in the Developer Documentation?

If you're unable to install your Module, you may be missing one or more of the required functions or files. The naming and location of your files are extremely important, too.

If you suspect errors, enable the Output Profiler or Template Debugger (see below) and check Apache's or PHP's `error_log`.

[ExpressionEngine's Control Panel Output and Debugging Preferences](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/system_admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html):
CP Home > Admin > System Administration > Output and Debugging

[image: ExpressionEngine Output and Debugging Preferences]

Comment: it comes up saying 'Module installed: Picture uploader' yet no tab apears, and whenever it goes back to the page it still says 'not installed' also where do you mean `Module_name`? is that in the install function where you do `$this->EE->db->insert('modules',$data);` or elsewhere?

Comment: When declaring your module in `upd.upload_pictures.php` it  should have the first letter of your module's name uppercased wherever it appears: `class Upload_pictures_upd{}` and `function Upload_pictures_upd()`.

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't work. Is there anything else it could possibly be?

Comment: Does your module appear in the `exp_modules` MySQL database table after you install it from the Control Panel?